# IMG disappearing in firefox only?

Tags: firefox, image

I have built the following page a while ago: http://www.cnplumbingandheating.co.uk/#page=about

However, the ID card (images/id-card.png) disappears in Firefox, although behaves as intended in Chrome, Safari and Opera. It was working in Firefox some time ago, and I have not edited the files or code since, yet this bug has appeared...

Can anybody shed any light as to what might be the cause, particularly if you cannot replicate it?

NOTE: The image reappears if you hover over it, but disappears on mouseout. There is no CSS/JS affecting this (as far as I can see).

Comment: i tried with firefox and i see the image of the id card. Then when i hover it, it moves. I think it behaves as you want.

Comment: Working as described in firefox 17.

Comment: This must mean its a bug on my local Firefox... I've tried deleting the cache, restarting and praying but no luck. Ill have to live with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem. I think it's working fine. Maybe a caching issue.
Anyway have a look. This is what i see when the page loads:

[image: first image]

and this is when i hover the id card:

[image: second image]

It seems it works well. By the way, nice website.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and esp. with the screenshots - it is appreciated. This is how I wanted it to work :) So all seems to be good.

Comment: For some reason however it doesn't display on my local firefox until I hover. I've tried clearing the cache etc but to no avail.

And thank you for your kind comments :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I hope you can get to display it correctly also on your browser anyway i wouldn't worry, since i gave you the proof i see it correctly :) Keep up the good work @BNewton.co.uk